# How to pass a parameter on ReactJS to setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that calls on my ReactJS app:

```
Charts.createNpsGraficoRespostas(nps_respostas_vida, chart_nps_vida , self)
```

This is the code of the function:

```
export function createNpsGraficoRespostas(array_nps_respostas, state_parameter, self){
...
self.setState({ state_parameter : chart_nps })
...
}
```

Did you see the parameter "state_parameter", I want to pass the value "chart_nps_vida" as a parameter to the setState function, but this it is not working.

This is what I want, but I want to use a parameter instead of use directly "chart_nps_vida".

```
    self.setState({ chart_nps_vida: chart_nps })
```

How can I get to make this works?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking right now. We can only guess what you're trying to do. Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming state_parameter is a string, this should work.

```
  export function createNpsGraficoRespostas(array_nps_respostas, state_parameter, self){
    ...
    self.setState({ [state_parameter] : chart_nps })
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You're asking to use the variable parameter name as the object fieldname. This cannot be done. The best solution would be this:

```
Charts.createNpsGraficoRespostas(nps_respostas_vida, {chart_nps_vida: chart_nps_vida} , self)

export function createNpsGraficoRespostas(array_nps_respostas, state_parameter, self){
    ...
    self.setState(state_parameter)
    ...
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer